# Python FPDF fill color of a cell based on an IF statement

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, fpdf

Team,

How do I change the cell background color of a table. For example, I want to change the cell background of column B items if it is "No" using FPDF and IF statement or other methods. That is if a No is in the cell, the "No" cell should be colored.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | No |
| Yes | No |

```
    if df.Column B.any() == "No":
        pdf.set_fill_color(193, 229, 252)
        pdf.cell(30, 10, 'No', 1, 1, 'C', True)
```

But it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the syntax error in `df.Column B`, `df["Column B"].any()` will always returns `True`.

You can try using [`iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) from [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) :

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_fill_color(255, 255, 255) #make a white-bg
pdf.set_font("Arial", "B", 12) # <-- ajudst here if needed
for col in df.columns:
    pdf.cell(30, 10, col, 1, 0, "C", 1)
pdf.ln(10) #a newline

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    pdf.set_font("Arial", "", 10)  # <-- ajudst here if needed
    pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column A"], 1, 0, "C")

    if row["Column B"] == "No":
        pdf.set_fill_color(193, 229, 252) #make a blue-bg
        pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column B"], 1, 0, "C", 1)
    else:
        pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column B"], 1, 0, "C")

    pdf.ln(10) #a newline

pdf.output("output.pdf", "F")
```

Output (*.pdf*) :

[image]

Equivalent with [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) (*in Jupyter*) :

```
(
    df.style
     .applymap(lambda x: "background-color: #C1E5FC"
               if x == "No" else "", subset=["Column B"])
)
```

[image]

***UPDATE :***

> Actually I have four columns. There are 2 columns before column A. How
> do I re-write for pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column A"], 1) for each column
> preceeding column B ?

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    pdf.set_font("Arial", "", 10)
    pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column 1"], 1, 0, "C") # <-- add this line
    pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column 2"], 1, 0, "C") # <-- add this line
    pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column A"], 1, 0, "C")

    if row["Column B"] == "No":
        pdf.set_fill_color(193, 229, 252) #make a blue-bg
        pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column B"], 1, 0, "C", 1)
    else:
        pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column B"], 1, 0, "C")

    pdf.ln(10) #a newline

pdf.output("output.pdf", "F")
```

Output :

[image]

*Input used :*

```
  Column 1 Column 2 Column A Column B
0        A        X      foo      Yes
1        B        Y      bar       No
2        C        Z      baz      Yes
```

Comment: @Timeless...Thanks....Actually I have four columns. There are 2 columns before column A. How do I re-write for pdf.cell(30, 10, row["Column A"], 1) for each column preceeding column B?

Comment: You're welcome and regarding your question, you just need to add`pdf.cell` for each column (*while, of course, preserving the order*). I updated my answer ;)